# node js api call with different domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

- using node js I need to call two different api, which are present in two different domains.
- one api works fine which is present in sports domain.
- another api which is present in players domain, which I added now thats where I am getting the error
  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`
- I debugged by putting console but not sure how to fix it.
- do I need to change the configuration. I even added routers
- providing my code snippet below.

**players domain node js code**

```or-tag-here
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const mime = require('mime-types');

const router = express.Router();
const ResponseUtil = require('../../utils/ResponseUtil');

router.get('/:rank/:jump', (req, res, next) => {
  const { originalUrl } = req;
  //console.log(" originalUrl  ", originalUrl);
  const mode = req.params.rank;
  const value = encodeURIComponent(req.params.jump);
  console.log("document 4--->", mode);
  console.log("for document Testing--->", mode);
           const url = `players/?id=890900-weweew`;

  axios
    .get(url, {
      headers: {
        authorization: req.headers.authorization,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("document--->", response);
      const file = Buffer.from(response.data.content, 'base64');
      const fileType = mime.contentType(response.data.contentInfo.fileType);
      const fileExtension = response.data.contentInfo.fileType.toLowerCase();
      const fileName = `filename=${response.data.contentInfo.id}.${fileExtension}`;
      res.set('Content-Type', fileType);
      res.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; ${fileName}`);
      res.send(file);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(e.response.status).send(e.response.data);
    });

    ResponseUtil.callService(res, url);


});

module.exports = router;
```

**sports domain node js code**

```or-tag-here
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ResponseUtil = require('../../utils/ResponseUtil');

router.get('/:rank/:jump', (req, res, next) => {

  const { originalUrl } = req;

  //console.log(" originalUrl  ", originalUrl);

  const mode = req.params.rank;

  const value = encodeURIComponent(req.params.jump);

  const url = `/sports?mode=sdioiosdio`;

  console.log("rank 3--->", mode);
  console.log("for document Testing--->", mode);


  ResponseUtil.callService(res, url);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Check the `url` you use in `axios.get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [axios document](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) your requst to `url` is not accomplished.
Maybe the destination is not reachable.
So the best error handling as document says is that you check for availability of `response` in error.

```
...
.catch((e) => {
      if(e.response){
        return res.status(e.response.status).send(e.response.data);
      }
      res.status(500).send(e.message || 'Something wrong');
    });
```

Comment: Hey I googled but not able to find any sample example...can you provide links of sample example so that I will build it from scratch